# Text field or button appears on outside of design?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

with the following code i had trouble adding text view or buttons. Every time i try it appers on the design page that the button is on the outside of the phone. i inserted a picture to show what i mean on design page.

http://postimg.org/image/dtqbnoqxv/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d1cbcb">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#767eca">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="label"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add `android:orientation="vertical"` to `LinearLayout` so that `Button` comes below `TextView`

Comment: Add android:orientation:"vertical" in your Main  Linear Layout

Comment: usually it should give a lint warning if no orientation is set. I guess you have disabled lint warnings in AS, but it should be enabled....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding android:orientation="vertical" or android:orientation="horizontal" of LinearLayout according your desire.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d1cbcb"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#767eca">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="label"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```